# App on Android closes when I enter more than 7 sequential numbers in text input box

Tags: android, html, textinput

I am testing an app I created in eclipse using both the android emulator and phone device, and found that any time I enter more than 7 sequential numbers in an input text box, the app immediately closes and the Eclipse LogCat dispalys: 01-14 20:52:12.888: A/libc(617): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000c (code=1), thread 631 (WebViewCoreThre)

Example input is '1234567890', but, form and app closes when I get to number 9. However, if I enter alphabetical chars after the 8th charactaer (e.g., '12345678AB') it works fine. See html clip below.

```
<label for="ContactNbr">Enter Contact Number:</label>
<input type="text" name="ContactNbr" id="ContactNbr" value="" />
```

Comment: You enter those 7 numbers, and then you hit enter? Have you tried other input types?

Comment: I have tested with both type="text" and type="number", both with the same result.  On some attempts, I can enter 8 or 9 numbers in a row, and sometimes less.

Comment: ...and I should add the app closed as I was selecting numbers on the touchscreen keypad, before I could even click the Enter/Submit button.